# /usr/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'azure.cli' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure')

Tags: python, azure-cli, archlinux

I am running a arch linux where i need to run "az login" with azure-cli but get this issue:

`az login /usr/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'azure.cli' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure')`

Also when checking which python version im running, python cannot load a shared lib:

`python -version python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

azure-cli lives in /home/user/lib/azure-cli/lib
and python is within that path

`whereis python python: /usr/bin/python /home/user/lib/azure-cli/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz`

What could be the underlying problem of not running these commands. Is it rather a python package issue or azure-cli?

I tried removing my python build thus its depended on other packages and configs like ansible etc. Which will only make this a bigger issue.

Comment: more information that could be related is that running pacman -Q python to check what im running via pacman: i get 
python 3.11.3-1,

Comment: Try to run `sudo pacman -S azure-cli` and then run `az login` and check once.

Comment: did that in my first try which is very logical, thus "error: target not found: azure-cli" when trying to fetch it and download via pacman @Harshitha

Answer (score 1):

> Error while finding module specification for 'azure.cli' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'):

The error means that the Azure CLI was unable to locate the required modules in the environment.

*You can try below methods to solve these kind of issues:*

1. Check the path of `Python` environment and where exactly it is installed, using below command.

```
 where python
```

2. Check if your system has the `libpython3.11.so.1.0` library installed using the command `ldd $(which python) | grep libpython`. If the library is not installed, execute `sudo apt-get install libpython3.11.1.`
3. Check the list of the modules present in the environment using `pip list`. It displays the installed packages with their current versions.

[image]

4. Sometimes, upgrading pip will solve the issue. Upgrade pip from the console using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` command.

   [image]
5. Install [`pip install azure-common`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-common/). Sometimes the python environment raises the *"error no module azure cli/azure found"* when they cannot find `azure. Common` library. It is a Microsoft Azure SDK for Python.
6. Check that the azure-cli binary is in the `PATH` of your system. If the azure-cli binary isn't existed in the PATH, add it using
   `export PATH=<path>:/home/user/lib/azure-cli/bin`.

*If still the persists, create a new virtual environment and proceed further.*

[Activate Virtual environment for Python](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)